# AJAX only picks first element id in a DJANGO loop

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, loops

AJAX only picks first element id in a DJANGO loop.

Wherever I click the "edit" button it brings the first post content. I've just similar metholodogy in other functions (for example a like button) but in this one I don't really see what it only picks the top element of the loop in every template. Please help.

This is what I came up with so far:

jS:

```
    //Edit

$('.editfunction').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault()
        var post_pk;
        var content = $('.textarea_edit').val();
        post_pk = $(this).data("post_pk");

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: `/post/${post_pk}/edit`,
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
            post_id: post_pk,
            textarea: content
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.modal-edit').modal('hide')
            var content = $('.textarea_edit').val()
            $(`.post-object-content${post_pk}`).html(content)
        }
        })
    })
```

FOR loop:

```
    {% for post in paginated_posts %}
<div style="padding: 10px;" id="{{post.id}}">
    <div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid;">
    <p>
    <h4><a href="{% url 'post_view' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
</p>
    <p style="display: inline-flex;">
      {% if post.author.profile.id %}
    by: <span style="font-weight: bold;"><a href="{% url 'profile_class' post.author.profile.id %}">&nbsp; {{ post.author }} &nbsp;</a></span>
    {% else %}
    by: <span style="font-weight: bold;">&nbsp; {{ post.author }} &nbsp;</span>    
    {% endif %}
    on {{ post.creation_date }}
    </p>
    <h5 class="card-text post-object-content{{post.id}}">{{ post.post_text }}</h5>
    
<!-- Edit -->
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% if user.id == post.author.id %}

<!-- Button modal edit-->
<small><a href="{% url 'post_view' post.pk %}">[Edit]</a></small>

<!-- Modal EDIT -->
<div class="modal fade modal-edit" id="edit" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content new-post-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Edit post {{ post.id }}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form method=post action="{% url 'edit' post.pk %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <textarea rows="10" class="form-control textarea_edit" name="textarea">{{post.post_text}}</textarea>
              <br>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary save editfunction" data-post_pk="{{ post.pk }}" type="submit" value="Save">Submit</button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please re-edit your question and add the `for loop`  you're working with...

Comment: What button or link was clicked to activate the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
var content = $('.textarea_edit').val();
```

This is working as intended, unfortunately. If there are multiple members of the class selector, .val() will grab the first element of the list of classes by that name (see https://api.jquery.com/val/ for details)

if you are wanting to do something with each of that class's textarea values, you can put them into an array by a process like:

```
var content = []

$('.textarea_edit').each(function(){
    content.push($(this).val()); 
});
```